# VB6 IDE Runtime - Sub/Function Exits unexpectedly after an error

Tags: vb6

Previously I've noticed some instances when running an App in the IDE causes unexpected behaviour.  But I've now (accidentally) found a reproducible set of circumstances that cause it to ignore error trapping (or lack of).

The code below shows the problem:

```
Private Sub Sub1()

    On Error Resume Next
    err.clear

    Call Sub2

    Debug.Print 10 / 0

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Found error in Sub1"
    End If

    Err.Clear

    Call Sub2

End Sub


Sub Sub2()

    ' On Error Resume Net
    err.clear

    Debug.Print 10 / 0

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Found error in Sub2"
    End If

End Sub
```

Sub1 calls Sub2.
I've REM'd the 'On Error Resume Next' line as if I'm debugging Sub2.  But when the error is reached (Debug.print 10 / 0), instead of the IDE halting, it *silently* exits to the calling routine.
So if I had disabled the error trapping so that I could debug Sub2,  the IDE would behave very oddly and just return the calling routine.
If I also disable the 'On Error Resume Next' in Sub1,  the IDE behaves as expected and does raise an error in Sub2.

The work around is *always* to disable error trapping immediately before calling a Sub/Function and then to enable it again after return. But that seems a kludge.   Does anyone know a 'fix' (hotfix that I've missed?).

I'm not suggesting that MS fix this (if it is a bug) - just wondering how others work round the problem.

Comment: Seems to match the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266173(v=vs.60).aspx): "On Error Resume Next causes execution to continue with the statement immediately following the statement that caused the run-time error, or *with the statement immediately following the most recent call out of the procedure* containing the On Error Resume Next statement." (My *emphasis*)

Comment: Hi Damien, thank you.  That's embarrassing (for not spotting that), but thank you for finding it. So it's expected behaviour (even though I think it can lead to confusion when debugging).  As expected behaviour, there probably won't be a work-around.  I was tempted to delete the question, but the question and your response might help others.  Thanks again. Ian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm generally using `Option->General->Break on All Errors: On` in the IDE. When the IDE hits an error it stops and waits for my confirmation. This happens even if there is an `On Error Resume Next`.

If the error is accounted for I have two options:

1. Skip to next line manually with <kbd>Ctrl+F9</kbd>
2. Right click menu `Toggle->Break on Unhandled Errors` and continue with <kbd>F5</kbd>

The latter option's sub-menu is similar to the choices in Options dialog but is a temporary setting per debugging sessions (until IDE is restarted).

The hard part is developing with `Break on All Errors`. Sometimes I have to use specially crafted typelibs that alter methods signatures to return LONGs instead of HRESULTs so that VB6 does not `Err.Raise` but to silently fail with a (checked) retval.

Developing with `Break on All Errors` tends to be mandatory for any VB6 project in excess of 100k LOC. For smaller ones you can buy t-shirts with `On Error Resume Next` slogan and enjoy the paycheck at the end of the month :-))